# Как обратиться к элементу по номеру внутри div? в css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Например имеется такая часть верстки:

```html
    <div id="Dot_1">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
</div>
```

Как обратиться к перому диву? Или к лбому другому по счёту? ( в css)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^__^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это называется псевдоклассы, их куча.

Данный псевдокласс который вам нужен `:nth-child`

```css
#Dot_1 div:nth-child(1){
color:red;
}

#Dot_1 div:nth-child(2){
background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="Dot_1">
  <div>11111</div>
  <div>22222</div>
  <div>33333</div>
  <div>44444</div>
  <div>55555</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```css
#Dot_1 div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#Dot_1 div:nth-child(2) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="Dot_1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Вот:

```
#Dot_1>div:first-child или #Dot_1>div:nth-child(1)
```