# Как обратиться к элементу внутри элемента?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Как обратиться к тегу `li`, который находиться в `div class="group"`?
Надо к каждому элементу `li` придать одно свойство через CSS, но без придачи `class` к каждому элементу `li`

*На сайте есть и другие элементы списка со своим стилем. Писать в `class` в каждом `li` не хочется*

```css
li{
  color: coral;
  background-color: bisque;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <ul>
    <li>0012</li>
    <li>0023</li>
    <li>0034</li>
    <li>0045</li>
    <li>0078</li>
    <li>0093</li>
    <li>0123</li>
    <li>0198</li>
    <li>0211</li>  
    <li>0236</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Например `.group li` или это Вам не подходит по каким-то причинам?

Comment: Если прям к каждому нужно отдельно обращаться - можно вспомнить про псевдо класс `:nth-child`... http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обратиться к элементу по номеру внутри div? в css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879270/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-div-%d0%b2-css)

Answer (score 0):

Для применения стилей к каждому n-ному элементу li внутри ul, можно использовать псевдокласс :nth-child().

Например, чтобы применить стили только к четным элементам li, можно использовать следующий CSS код:

```css
div.group ul li:nth-child(even) {
  color: coral;
  background-color: bisque;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <ul>
    <li>0012</li>
    <li>0023</li>
    <li>0034</li>
    <li>0045</li>
    <li>0078</li>
    <li>0093</li>
    <li>0123</li>
    <li>0198</li>
    <li>0211</li>  
    <li>0236</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

А для того, чтобы применить стили только к нечетным элементам li, можно использовать следующий CSS код:

```css
div.group ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  color: coral;
  background-color: bisque;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <ul>
    <li>0012</li>
    <li>0023</li>
    <li>0034</li>
    <li>0045</li>
    <li>0078</li>
    <li>0093</li>
    <li>0123</li>
    <li>0198</li>
    <li>0211</li>  
    <li>0236</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Также можно задать каждому элементу номеруя его черёдность:

```css
div.group ul li:nth-child(1) {
    color: red;
}

div.group ul li:nth-child(2){
    color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <ul>
    <li>0012</li>
    <li>0023</li>
    <li>0034</li>
    <li>0045</li>
    <li>0078</li>
    <li>0093</li>
    <li>0123</li>
    <li>0198</li>
    <li>0211</li>  
    <li>0236</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

:nth-child() считает все дочерние элементы родительского элемента, а не только элементы с определенным классом или тегом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставляйте воспроизводимые примеры, только там, где можно *запустить* код, чтобы увидеть результат. В других случаях, вставляйте код, в 6 апострофов / обратных кавычек.

Comment: Такого правила нет, просто рекомендация. Такой "воспроизводимый" код может ввести новых пользователей в заблуждение, а вы, если заметили, то автор вопроса, новый участник.